# What are the scenarios where we can use Actionresult in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know that actionresult is the base class which is inherited by ViewResult,JsonResult etc. but I want to know under what circumstances we can call ActionResult directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to return result based on condition

```
public ActionResult TestAction()
{
    if(true)
        return View();
    else
        Json(anyObject);
}
```